# C# OPENXML XLSX Custom Column width

Tags: c#, openxml, xlsx

C# newbie here!

I need to create a small console application to convert CSV files into XLSX files.

I have all my styles and data working, but I want to set a different (from default) width on some columns. And after a day of searching and reading I still can't figure out how to get it to work.

As an example I want to

- set columns A and C to a width of 30
- Set column D to a width of 20

Any help or tips would be great.
My code right now below

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;

namespace xml_test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {          
            string xlsx_path = @"c:\test\test.xlsx";
            string CSV_Path = @"c:\test\test.csv";

            // Skal nok ha en try her i tilfellet et dolument er åpent eller noe slikt...
            using (var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(xlsx_path, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
            {
                spreadsheet.AddWorkbookPart();
                spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();
                var wsPart = spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
                wsPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet();                            
                SheetFormatProperties sheetFormatProperties = new SheetFormatProperties()
                {
                    DefaultColumnWidth = 15,
                    DefaultRowHeight = 15D                 
                };

                wsPart.Worksheet.Append(sheetFormatProperties);               
                var stylesPart = spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorkbookStylesPart>();
                stylesPart.Stylesheet = new Stylesheet();

                // Font list
                // Create a bold font
                stylesPart.Stylesheet.Fonts = new Fonts();
                Font bold_font = new Font();         // Bold font
                Bold bold = new Bold();
                bold_font.Append(bold);

                // Add fonts to list
                stylesPart.Stylesheet.Fonts.AppendChild(new Font());
                stylesPart.Stylesheet.Fonts.AppendChild(bold_font); // Bold gets fontid = 1
                stylesPart.Stylesheet.Fonts.Count = 2;

                // Create fills list
                stylesPart.Stylesheet.Fills = new Fills();

                // create red fill for failed tests
                var formatRed = new PatternFill() { PatternType = PatternValues.Solid };
                formatRed.ForegroundColor = new ForegroundColor { Rgb = HexBinaryValue.FromString("FF6600") }; // red fill
                formatRed.BackgroundColor = new BackgroundColor { Indexed = 64 };

                // Create green fill for passed tests
                var formatGreen = new PatternFill() { PatternType = PatternValues.Solid };
                formatGreen.ForegroundColor = new ForegroundColor { Rgb = HexBinaryValue.FromString("99CC00") }; // green fill
                formatGreen.BackgroundColor = new BackgroundColor { Indexed = 64 };

                // Create blue fill
                var formatBlue = new PatternFill() { PatternType = PatternValues.Solid };
                formatBlue.ForegroundColor = new ForegroundColor { Rgb = HexBinaryValue.FromString("81DAF5") };
                formatBlue.BackgroundColor = new BackgroundColor { Indexed = 64 };

                // Create Light Green fill
                var formatLightGreen = new PatternFill() { PatternType = PatternValues.Solid };
                formatLightGreen.ForegroundColor = new ForegroundColor { Rgb = HexBinaryValue.FromString("F1F8E0") };
                formatLightGreen.BackgroundColor = new BackgroundColor { Indexed = 64 };

                // Append fills to list
                stylesPart.Stylesheet.Fills.AppendChild(new Fill { PatternFill = new PatternFill { PatternType = PatternValues.None } }); // required, reserved by Excel
                stylesPart.Stylesheet.Fills.AppendChild(new Fill { PatternFill = new PatternFill { PatternType = PatternValues.Gray125 } }); // required, reserved by Excel
                stylesPart.Stylesheet.Fills.AppendChild(new Fill { PatternFill = formatRed }); // Red gets fillid = 2
                stylesPart.Stylesheet.Fills.AppendChild(new Fill { PatternFill = formatGreen }); // Green gets fillid = 3
                stylesPart.Stylesheet.Fills.AppendChild(new Fill { PatternFill = formatBlue }); // Blue gets fillid = 4, old format1
                stylesPart.Stylesheet.Fills.AppendChild(new Fill { PatternFill = formatLightGreen }); // LightGreen gets fillid = 5, old format2
                stylesPart.Stylesheet.Fills.Count = 6;

                // Create border list
                stylesPart.Stylesheet.Borders = new Borders();

                // Create thin borders for passed/failed tests and default cells
                LeftBorder leftThin = new LeftBorder() { Style = BorderStyleValues.Thin };
                RightBorder rightThin = new RightBorder() { Style = BorderStyleValues.Thin };
                TopBorder topThin = new TopBorder() { Style = BorderStyleValues.Thin };
                BottomBorder bottomThin = new BottomBorder() { Style = BorderStyleValues.Thin };

                Border borderThin = new Border();
                borderThin.Append(leftThin);
                borderThin.Append(rightThin);
                borderThin.Append(topThin);
                borderThin.Append(bottomThin);

                // Create thick borders for headings
                LeftBorder leftThick = new LeftBorder() { Style = BorderStyleValues.Thick };
                RightBorder rightThick = new RightBorder() { Style = BorderStyleValues.Thick };
                TopBorder topThick = new TopBorder() { Style = BorderStyleValues.Thick };
                BottomBorder bottomThick = new BottomBorder() { Style = BorderStyleValues.Thick };

                Border borderThick = new Border();
                borderThick.Append(leftThick);
                borderThick.Append(rightThick);
                borderThick.Append(topThick);
                borderThick.Append(bottomThick);

                // Add borders to list
                stylesPart.Stylesheet.Borders.AppendChild(new Border());
                stylesPart.Stylesheet.Borders.AppendChild(borderThin);
                stylesPart.Stylesheet.Borders.AppendChild(borderThick);
                stylesPart.Stylesheet.Borders.Count = 3;

                // Create blank cell format list
                stylesPart.Stylesheet.CellStyleFormats = new CellStyleFormats();
                stylesPart.Stylesheet.CellStyleFormats.Count = 1;
                stylesPart.Stylesheet.CellStyleFormats.AppendChild(new CellFormat());

                // Create cell format list
                stylesPart.Stylesheet.CellFormats = new CellFormats();
                // empty one for index 0, seems to be required
                stylesPart.Stylesheet.CellFormats.AppendChild(new CellFormat());


                // cell format for failed tests, Styleindex = 1, Red fill and bold text
                stylesPart.Stylesheet.CellFormats.AppendChild(new CellFormat { FormatId = 0, FontId = 1, BorderId = 2, FillId = 2, ApplyFill = true }).AppendChild(new Alignment { Horizontal = HorizontalAlignmentValues.Center });

                // cell format for passed tests, Styleindex = 2, Green fill and bold text
                stylesPart.Stylesheet.CellFormats.AppendChild(new CellFormat { FormatId = 0, FontId = 1, BorderId = 2, FillId = 3, ApplyFill = true }).AppendChild(new Alignment { Horizontal = HorizontalAlignmentValues.Center });

                // cell format for blue background, Styleindex = 3, blue fill and bold text
                stylesPart.Stylesheet.CellFormats.AppendChild(new CellFormat { FormatId = 0, FontId = 1, BorderId = 1, FillId = 4, ApplyFill = true }).AppendChild(new Alignment { Horizontal = HorizontalAlignmentValues.Center });

                // cell format for light green background, Styleindex = 4, light green fill and bold text
                stylesPart.Stylesheet.CellFormats.AppendChild(new CellFormat { FormatId = 0, FontId = 1, BorderId = 1, FillId = 5, ApplyFill = true }).AppendChild(new Alignment { Horizontal = HorizontalAlignmentValues.Center });

                // default cell style, thin border and rest default
                stylesPart.Stylesheet.CellFormats.AppendChild(new CellFormat { FormatId = 0, FontId = 0, BorderId = 1, FillId = 0, ApplyFill = true }).AppendChild(new Alignment { Horizontal = HorizontalAlignmentValues.Center });

                stylesPart.Stylesheet.CellFormats.Count = 6;
                stylesPart.Stylesheet.Save();
                var sheetData = wsPart.Worksheet.AppendChild(new SheetData());                
                TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(CSV_Path);
                parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
                parser.SetDelimiters(";");
                while (!parser.EndOfData)
                {
                    string line = parser.ReadLine();                    
                    string[] elements = line.Split(';');
                    var row = sheetData.AppendChild(new Row());
                    if (parser.LineNumber == 2)
                    {                        
                        foreach (string element in elements)
                        {
                            row.AppendChild(new Cell() { CellValue = new CellValue(element), DataType = CellValues.String, StyleIndex = 3 });                            
                        }
                    }
                    if (parser.LineNumber == 3)
                    {
                        foreach (string element in elements)
                        {                            
                            if (elements.First() == element && element == "Pass")
                            {
                                row.AppendChild(new Cell() { CellValue = new CellValue(element), DataType = CellValues.String, StyleIndex = 2 });
                            }
                            else if (elements.First() == element && element == "Fail")
                            {
                                row.AppendChild(new Cell() { CellValue = new CellValue(element), DataType = CellValues.String, StyleIndex = 1 });
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                                row.AppendChild(new Cell() { CellValue = new CellValue(element), DataType = CellValues.String, StyleIndex = 5 });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (parser.LineNumber == 4)
                    {
                        foreach (string element in elements)
                        {
                            row.AppendChild(new Cell() { CellValue = new CellValue(element), DataType = CellValues.String, StyleIndex = 4 });                            
                        }
                    }
                    if (parser.LineNumber > 4 || parser.LineNumber == -1)
                    {
                        int i = 0;
                        foreach (string element in elements)
                        {
                            if (i == 1 && element == "Pass")
                            {
                                row.AppendChild(new Cell() { CellValue = new CellValue(element), DataType = CellValues.String, StyleIndex = 2 });
                            }
                            else if (i == 1 && element == "Fail")
                            {
                                row.AppendChild(new Cell() { CellValue = new CellValue(element), DataType = CellValues.String, StyleIndex = 1 });
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                row.AppendChild(new Cell() { CellValue = new CellValue(element), DataType = CellValues.String, StyleIndex = 5 });
                            }
                            i++;
                        }
                    }
                }                
                var sheets = spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(new Sheets());
                sheets.AppendChild(new Sheet() { Id = spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(wsPart), SheetId = 1, Name = "sheet1" });             
                spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save();                
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In order to set the column widths you need to create a [`Columns`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.columns) element which can contain one or more [`Column`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.column) children.

Each `Column` class can apply to more than one column in the Excel file. The `Min` and `Max` properties define the first and last column that the `Column` applies to (inclusive).

In your example, you'll need to define two `Column` instances, one with `Min=1` and `Max=2` and the other with both `Min` and `Max` set to `4` (the `Min` and `Max` are numeric with A=1, B =2 etc).

The `Columns` collection needs to be added to the `Worksheet` before the `SheetData` element.

Adding the following code after `stylesPart.Stylesheet.Save();` but before `var sheetData = wsPart.Worksheet.AppendChild(new SheetData());` should achieve what you are after:

```
Columns columns = new Columns();

columns.Append(new Column() { Min = 1, Max = 3, Width = 20, CustomWidth = true });
columns.Append(new Column() { Min = 4, Max = 4, Width = 30, CustomWidth = true });

wsPart.Worksheet.Append(columns);
```

Note1: Any columns not covered by the `Column` classes will have a default width.

Note2: All properties of the column (Min, Max, Width, CustomWidth) should be specified. Otherwise Excel will decide that the file is corrupted.

Comment: This solved everything. I think my biggest mistakes where my placement of the colums code. I had it placed after i created sheetdata in the beginning.

Comment: Glad I could help @Zankul. OpenXML is particular about the order of things which can be really frustrating!

Comment: Thank you so very much. I have been looking everywhere for a more descriptive answer. I must have been fighting with the hierarchy of what code comes first for so long, but with no guidance. Thumbs up my good sir.

Comment: Thanks @fluffy, I really appreciate the feedback :)

Comment: Columns element must appear before the SheetData element in the WorkSheet.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45231668/1082063.

Comment: This code does not work completely correctly.
When I set the column width to 20 Code: Append(new Column() { Min = 1, Max = 3, Width = 20, CustomWidth = true }); in the program and then open MSExcel and look at the column width, MSExcel shows the width to 19.29.