# OpenXML Custom column width not working

Tags: c#, openxml

I'm trying to change the width of some excel columns. I've tried everything but I keep getting empty excel documents, my excel file works fine without this addition:

```
Columns columns = new Columns();

columns.Append(new Column() { Min = 1, Max = 3, Width = 20, CustomWidth = true });
columns.Append(new Column() { Min = 4, Max = 4, Width = 30, CustomWidth = true });

wsPart.Worksheet.Append(columns);
```

But as soon as I add this [like this user suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38150078/6953120), I have to repair my excel file, and it will be empty. I get this error: "Replaced Part: /xl/worksheets/sheet.xml part with XML error.  Load error. Line 1, column 0.
". And the 'repaired' file is empty.

My code is basically the same as that from the [MSDN example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc861607.aspx)

I've tried many different ways of changing the column width, so I think the problem lies elsewhere. I can't seem to figure out what's wrong.

EDIT: Full code

```
_document = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(newFileName, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);

_workbookPart = _document.AddWorkbookPart();
_workbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();

WorksheetPart worksheetPart = _workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetViews(new SheetView { WorkbookViewId = 0, ShowGridLines = new BooleanValue(false) }), new SheetData());

_document.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(new Sheets());

Sheet sheet = new Sheet { Id = _document.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart), SheetId = 1, Name = "Sheet1" };
_workbookPart.Workbook.Sheets.Append(sheet);


WorkbookStylesPart stylesPart = _workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorkbookStylesPart>();
stylesPart.Stylesheet = CreateStylesheet();
stylesPart.Stylesheet.Save();

Columns columns = new Columns();

columns.Append(new Column() { Min = 1, Max = 3, Width = 20, CustomWidth = true });
columns.Append(new Column() { Min = 4, Max = 4, Width = 30, CustomWidth = true });

worksheetPart.Worksheet.Append(columns);

_sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();
```

Comment: You need to save sheet after you make changes to column-width.

Comment: I've done that, didn't help

Comment: Can you post all of your code please? The OpenXml schema defines an order for the elements - I would guess you are just adding the `Columns` at the wrong point relative to other elements...

Comment: I've added the code in an edit above^^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The order of your elements is slightly out. The `Columns` should be placed *before* the `SheetData` rather than after. The relevant part of the XML schema for a Worksheet is:

```
<xsd:complexType name="CT_Worksheet">
    <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="sheetPr" type="CT_SheetPr" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="dimension" type="CT_SheetDimension" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="sheetViews" type="CT_SheetViews" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="sheetFormatPr" type="CT_SheetFormatPr" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="cols" type="CT_Cols" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xsd:element name="sheetData" type="CT_SheetData" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
```

To fix your code you could either remove the `SheetData` from your `new Worksheet` line and add the `SheetData` after the `Columns`:

```
worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetViews(new SheetView { WorkbookViewId = 0, ShowGridLines = new BooleanValue(false) }));

//....code omitted for brevity

Columns columns = new Columns();

columns.Append(new Column() { Min = 1, Max = 3, Width = 20, CustomWidth = true });
columns.Append(new Column() { Min = 4, Max = 4, Width = 30, CustomWidth = true });

worksheetPart.Worksheet.Append(columns);
worksheetPart.Worksheet.Append(new SheetData());
```

OR you could leave the `new Worksheet` code as-is and use the [`InsertBefore`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc821755(v=office.15).aspx) method when adding the `Columns` to insert them before the `SheetData`:

```
Columns columns = new Columns();

columns.Append(new Column() { Min = 1, Max = 3, Width = 20, CustomWidth = true });
columns.Append(new Column() { Min = 4, Max = 4, Width = 30, CustomWidth = true });

var sheetdata = worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();
worksheetPart.Worksheet.InsertBefore(columns, sheetdata);
```

One other thing to note - you ought to wrap the `SpreadsheetDocument.Create` in a using statement. This will clean up any resources and save the file for you at the end of your changes i.e.:

```
using (var _document = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(filename, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
{
    //all your OpenXml code here...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I forgot I was adding the sheetdata up there. I cant do the using part because I build the excel dynamically, but it works perfectly now!

Comment: Excellent, glad I could help @Litrico.