# Repaired Records : Cell information from worksheet created

Tags: java, c#, excel, openxml

I'm receiving an error when opening my OpenXML created spreadsheet. The error is as follows.

> repaired record : xl/worksheets/sheet.xml  partial cell information

```
private void SavexlsExcelFile(String fullPathName)
    {
        using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(fullPathName, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
        {

            WorkbookPart workbookPart = document.AddWorkbookPart();
            workbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();

            worksheetPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
            worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet();

            Columns columns = new Columns();

            worksheetPart.Worksheet.AppendChild(columns);

            Sheets sheets = workbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(new Sheets());

            Sheet sheet = new Sheet() { Id = workbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart), SheetId = 1, Name = "Sheet" };
            sheets.Append(sheet);

            workbookPart.Workbook.Save();

            sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.AppendChild(new SheetData());


            List<List<string>> dataRow = new List<List<string>>();
            List<String> dtRow = new List<String>();

            Row row = new Row();

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; j++)
                {
                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                        Cell dataCell = new Cell();
                        dataCell.DataType = CellValues.String;
                        CellValue cellValue = new CellValue();

                        cellValue.Text = dataGridView1.Columns[j].Name;
                        dataCell.StyleIndex = 2;
                        dataCell.Append(cellValue);
                        row.AppendChild(dataCell);
                        //dataColumn.Add(dataGridView1.Columns[j].Name);
                    }
                    dtRow.Add(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString());
                }
            }

            dataRow.Add(dtRow);
            sheetData.AppendChild(row);

            row = new Row();

            foreach (List<string> datarow in dataRow)
            {
                row = new Row();
                foreach(string dtrow in datarow)
                {
                    row.Append(ConstructCell(dtrow, CellValues.String, 2));
                }
                sheetData.AppendChild(row);
            }
            worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();
        }
    }
    private Cell ConstructCell(string value, CellValues dataType, uint styleIndex = 0)
    {
        return new Cell()
        {
            CellValue = new CellValue(value),
            DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(dataType),
            StyleIndex = styleIndex
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 issues here that I can see. The first is that your use of `Columns` is incorrect. You should use `Columns` if you wish to control things such as the width of a column. To use `Columns` correctly, you'll need to add child `Column` elements. For example (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40089755/openxml-custom-column-width-not-working/40106848#40106848)):

```
Columns columns = new Columns();

columns.Append(new Column() { Min = 1, Max = 3, Width = 20, CustomWidth = true });
columns.Append(new Column() { Min = 4, Max = 4, Width = 30, CustomWidth = true });
```

In your sample you could just remove the following two lines

```
Columns columns = new Columns();
worksheetPart.Worksheet.AppendChild(columns);
```

The second issue is the `StyleIndex` you are using; the style doesn't exist in your document because you haven't added it. The easiest thing to do here is to just remove the `StyleIndex` altogether.

When debugging files like this, it's always worth looking at the [OpenXml Productivity Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30425). You can open a generated file in the tool and validate it to see what errors you have in your file.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I solved the problem this way.

Comment: Hi @SJ.Lee if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

All the text in Excel is stored under a shared string table. You need to insert the string in shared string table:

```
string text = dataGridView1.Columns[j].Name; 
cell.DataType = CellValues.SharedString;

if (!_spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.GetPartsOfType<SharedStringTablePart>().Any())
{
    _spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<SharedStringTablePart>();
}

var sharedStringTablePart = _spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.GetPartsOfType<SharedStringTablePart>().First();
if (sharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable == null)
{
    sharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable = new SharedStringTable();
}
//Iterate through shared string table to check if the value is already present.
foreach (SharedStringItem ssItem in sharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable.Elements<SharedStringItem>())
{
    if (ssItem.InnerText == text)
    {
        cell.CellValue = new CellValue(ssItem.ElementsBefore().Count().ToString());
        SaveChanges();
        return;
    }
}
// The text does not exist in the part. Create the SharedStringItem.
var item = sharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable.AppendChild(new SharedStringItem(new Text(text)));
cell.CellValue = new CellValue(item.ElementsBefore().Count().ToString());
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.